# Retornar objeto con mismo valor

Tags: javascript

La funcion llamada 'buscarAmigo' recibe como argumento un array llamado 'amigos' que contiene
recibe un string llamado 'nombre'.
Debe devolver el objeto cuya propiedad 'nombre' coincida con el string 'nombre' recibido por argumento.
Ej:

```
var amigos = [{ nombre: 'fran', edad: 20} , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }];
buscarAmigo(amigos, 'fran') debe devolver { nombre: 'fran', edad: 20};
```

Lo hice de esta manera y no se como continuarlo

```
function buscarAmigo(amigos, nombre) {
  if(amigos[nombre] === 'nombre'){
    return [nombre]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function buscarAmigos(amigo, nombres){
    amigos.map(data=>{
        if(data.nombre === nombres){
            console.log(data) 
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es eso? ¿Qué hace? ¿Cómo funciona? ¿En que falló el OP? ¿Qué consejo le darías para mejorar?

Comment: var amigos es un array para recorrer array existe forEach y .map que recorren los objetos de un array Busca tutorial para aprender mas funciones de arrays.